# Using animation set for setCustomAnimation in fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-animation, fragmenttransaction

I want to use custom animation in fragment transaction of my app. But thing is I have to create my animation programmatically. So I have used animation set and my animation is ready. But `transaction.setCustomAnimation(...)` needs to pass resource IDs of animations. So, what should I do?

Comment: you can use the predefined animations `android.R.anim.animationName` or use your own `R.anim.animationName`

Comment: override `onCreateAnimator`

Comment: I say that I have to create my animation programmatically @MohamedRa.

Comment: Can you explain a little more @pskink?

Comment: Do you mean onCreateAnimation of fragments? @pskink

Comment: @A.Badakhshan  you can only pass `ResourceId` to the `setCustomAnimation(...)`

Comment: i mean https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateAnimator(int,%20boolean,%20int)

Comment: I'm using support fragments, so in my case is onCreateAnimation. This way I will only have access to one animation of transaction.

Comment: what `"one animation"`?

Comment: Enter animation will be there. How can I access to other 3 animations (exit, popEnter, popExit)?

Comment: did you override that method? if not yet, do that, call the `super`, use `Log.d` to dump all the params passed to that method, run your app again and watch the `logcat`

Comment: I have override that method, but I'll check your solution. Thank you.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Please help.
Actually I want to open fragment from list item position dynamically.

Comment: I did not found any solution for this. I don't know if anybody had a solution for this.